# iOS Increment play count, last played date, etc manually

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem

I have a music app that plays short snippets of songs. I'd like to be able to increment the play count of the song, update the last played date, etc of these songs when they have been played.

I've searched google and the SDK and can't find any references on setting these values, only getting..

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Edit: I'd like for this data to be synced with the data displayed in iTunes, as opposed to storing a local copy of a play count that only my app will see.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What framework are you using or do you do everything on your own? Do you need the data to be persistent? If so, what persistent storage are you currently using? How do you currently store the titles/sniplets etc?

Comment: The app works by loading music from the itunes library and plays the AVPlayerItems using AVPlayer. A random snippet is generated just before it plays. I'd like the play count etc to be synced with itunes and displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

use a persistent data. ie; data base. it wont eat up much of memory but allows you to save necessary data. When you play a song compare its key like id or title and increment in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like for the play count etc to be synced with the iTunes one however. This will only store a copy local to my app.

Comment: you mean to say the count should be incremented if the user logs in from other device and plays it also?

Comment: I don't want only my app to be able to see the play count changes, but for them to sync to iTunes and be displayed their as well. (i.e These values in iTunes to update: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3423599/iTunes%20Play%20Count.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the iTunes Database is read-only